# How come my image disappears when I use percentage and appears when I use pixels?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a picture on my home page.  I made a container and a div within the container.  When I use pixels as width and height the picture appears but when I use 100% it does not. I tried changing the container to pixels to see if the image would render but it did not.

```
<div class="container" height="100%" width="100%">
    <div class="splash-div" ; style="background-image: url('../../Images/laptopboy.jpg'); background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;">

    </div>
</div>
```

Why doesn't the picture appear when I use the percentage for height and width?

Comment: Make sure the parent tag has an existing width and height.

Comment: for a % to work the parent styling is important too

Comment: Try to remove the ; after class="splash-div"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your image path.

You have entered a wrong path of image file.

Change path and try again.